# check box checked value not passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input checkbox, whose value is always logging on the console as false even when the box itself is checked. Am I forgetting to do something , am I not passing something needed? I am fairly new to React and js. My apologies for not putting in all the code for some reason stackOverflow wont let me paste all of it

Thank you for your help.

```
class Orders extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchOrders();
  }

  complete = () => {
    const completed = document.getElementById("complete").checked;
    // console.log("this is complete", completed);
    if (completed.checked === true) {
      // text.style.display = "block";
      console.log("im am checked");
    } else {
      console.log("im am NOT checked");
      //text.style.display = "none";
    }
  };

<input>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="complete"
                    id="complete"
                    onChange={() => this.complete()}
                  ></input>
                </td>
```

Comment: I think your condition is wrong. it should be `completed === true`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the `checked` property in the target element. This should work.

```
  const complete = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      console.log("im am checked");
    } else {
      console.log("im am NOT checked");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="complete"
        id="complete"
        onChange={(e) => complete(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: thank you ultimoTG that was it, and Kacper Biedka you definetly shed a light. thank you both

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a selector like this with React, this misses the point of the library. It's probably a problem that appeared when you copied the code but the html elements should be returned with the render() function. Instead you should pass the event to your callback function and use the event passed by the dom element like this :

```
class Orders extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchOrders();
  }

  complete = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      console.log("im am checked");
    } else {
      console.log("im am NOT checked");
    }
  };
```

Comment: Kacper Biedka, makes since, but how weird if I log the e.target.value i get back "on", every time i click on the box

Comment: Sorry, passed in the wrong value, use e.target.checked instead, edited the code ;)